# Automatic new lines in cells in a table to fit page width

Tags: tables

I'd like to let latex automatically put a new line in cells so to fit the table in the page width, is this possible?

For example this code would show the table but the table would not fit in the page width:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c| @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c|c}
\hline 
This is a very long table and cannot fit in the page width & another long words & more long words \\
\hline 
\hline 
example & example & example of a lot of text here so this should also go to multiple lines in this cell \\
\hline 
A & B & C \\
\hline 
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: you have the wrong syntax for `tabular*` (it needs a width argument) but you want `tabularx` from the package of the same name. Please always post complete docuemnts not fragments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good catch, I just corrected it to the right syntax

Comment: The code is still not usable as posted, but just use tabularx instead of tabular* and change at least one of the c to X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tabularx` and the `X` specifier.  The `booktabs` package allows for less tight setting around horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}%
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering%
\caption{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\toprule
This is a very long table and cannot fit in the page width & another long words & more long words \\
\midrule
\midrule
example & example & example of a lot of text here so this should also go to multiple lines in this cell \\
\midrule
A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want centred lines in cells, you can define a new column type with the `array package`, e.g.:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

And if you want  multiline cells to be vertically centred, you have to redefine the X type with:

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}%
```

Example:

[image]

If you want vertical lines (not recommended) that cross horizontal lines, you can't use booktabs. However, you still can have horizontal rules of different thicknesses with the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` from the `makecell` package. But you then lose the supplementary vertical space introduced by booktabs around  horizontal lines. Makecell has a command to do that (`\makegapedcells`) but it doesn't seem to work with `X`  cells. So one has to use the `cellspace` package, that defines a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}%
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering%
\caption{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{S{X}|S{X}|S{X}}
\Xhline{0.8pt}
This is a very long table and cannot fit in the page width & another long words & more long words \\
\hline\hline
example & example & example of a lot of text here so this should also go to multiple lines in this cell \\
\hline
A & B & C \\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks work like charm.  If I do: {X|X|X} the horizontal lines get cut, they do not pass on top of the vertical lines, anyway to make them pass over the vertical lines?

Comment: Then you can't use `booktabs` You can still have rules of different thicknesses thanks to the `makecell` package, and you have to add `cellspace` in order to have a better vertical spacing. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

Without any extra packages, you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering%
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
              }
\hline
This is a very long table and cannot fit in the page width & another long words & more long words \\
\hline
\hline
example & example & example of a lot of text here so this should also go to multiple lines in this cell \\
\hline
A & B & C \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want vertical center alignment, replace `p` with `m`.